# Angular - Mat-paginator is not working for multiple mat-tabs to display excel data

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-material-table

I'm trying to use mat-tabs to display excel data each tab contains mat-paginator, but mat-paginator only works for first tab rest of the tabs paginator is not working. I need mat-paginator to work on each tab can anyone help me to solve this?

```
 <input type="file" (change)="OnFileChange($event)" #file >
  <mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" (selectedTabChange)="display($event)">
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let c of allnames" label="{{c}}">
      <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:auto; white-space: nowrap;">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let name of displayedColumns;" matColumnDef="{{name}}">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="background-color: #f5f6fa; font-size:100%">
              {{name}}
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dt">
              {{dt[name]}}
            </td>

          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

        </table>
        <mat-paginator #userPaginator [length]="dataSource?.data.length" [pageSizeOptions]="[7,10,100]"
          showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>

typescript

display(data: any): void {
    this.newData1 = [];
    this.displayedColumns = [];
    this.newData1 = this.salldata[data.tab.textLabel];
    this.displayedColumns = this.newData1[0];
    var tempData = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.newData1.length; i++) {
      var tempRow = new Object();
      for (var j = 0; j < this.newData1[i].length; j++) {
        if ( this.newData1[i][j] != undefined) {
         
         var tempDisplayName = this.displayedColumns;
         tempRow[tempDisplayName[j]] = this.newData1[i][j];         
        }

      }   
     
      tempData.push(tempRow);
      //console.log(tempData)
    }
    tempData.shift();
    this.newTempData = tempData;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(tempData);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;  

  }


  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/editor-angular-editor-idkgfh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,package.json

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly is not working?

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly is not working?

Comment: Basically I'm importing excel sheet and trying to display all the data of excel sheet by tab wise(Mat-tabs) eg: sheet1 data in tab1, sheet2 data in tab2 and so on Mat-paginator is working for first tab but when I switch to next tab paginator is not working I need dynamic paginator according to the excel sheet like Excel1 may have 3 sheets, excel2 may have 10 sheets.... Thank you

Comment: I have attached stackblitz link of my code I have installed some dependency but still there is a dependency issue but it works fine in my laptop im sorry. Can anyone help me to solve the mat paginator I don't want to add multiple datasource and paginator I need it to work dynamically thanks in advance